# Assigning values to image pixels

Tags: matlab

I want assign values of previous frame , where the values in next frame is zero

```
if (n_image(:,:,1)==0 && n_image(:,:,2)==0 && n_image(:,:,3)==0)
               n_image(:,:,1)=grabbed_image(:,:,1);
               n_image(:,:,2)=grabbed_image(:,:,2);
               n_image(:,:,3)=grabbed_image(:,:,3);
end
```

ERROR:

> Operands to the `||` and `&&` operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing logical conditions with logical indexing

```
to_replace = all( n_image == 0, 3 );  %// logical index for pixels to be replaces
n_image = bsxfun(@times, n_image, ~to_replace) + bsxfun(@times, grabbed_image, to_replace);
```

Using indexing instead of multiplication

```
to_replace = to_replace(:,:,[1 1 1]);  %// replicate logical indices to channel dimension
n_image(to_replace) = grabbed_image(to_replace);
```

Comment: what the first line is doing?

Comment: @HrishabhPrajapati looks for all pixels that are zero across the third dimension

Comment: @ Shai I am trying your code,  i am getting object ,but(on the pixels) where the value is 0  I am getting white background , not the previous background.

Comment: Actually I am passing the background through a function , I think that's why it is creating a problem , but i am not able to resolve it.

Comment: Thank very much Shai , Your code helped me very much and now i  found out my problem . There was some problem of datatypes, and finally i have to use minus.

Comment: @ Shai Sir, may u provide me the code for background calculation. I want this background in image form.I have used averaging but it is not good to use it.It is not giving the correct results.

Comment: @HrishabhPrajapati background subtraction is a very broad topic. not fit for a comment here.

Comment: @ Shai  Sir , I need your help please . I have sent u fb req too. if u wish we can talk there sir.

Comment: @HrishabhPrajapati I do not do FB. please ask in stackoverflow.

Comment: @ Shai  Sir can u please  help  to give me a start how to write  write code for  1 gaussian or GMM for background estimation for color video stream. I need  your very much help sir.